# Variable Defining As String

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var allMatches:Number = soloStats[0] + duoStats[0] + squadStats[0]
```

When I try to make this variable a number, allMatches is a number but the values in it join as a string (for example 1, 2, and 3 join together as 123 instead of 6).

All the stats values are numbers and are successfully used at other times as a number, however in this variable they act like strings.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure stat arrays really has number values? Check this with `trace(getQualifiedClassName(soloStats[0]));`. Quick fix is to convert values like this: `var allMatches:Number = Number(soloStats[0]) + Number(duoStats[0]) + Number(squadStats[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you store the numbers as strings in your array.
You can use `parseInt` to get a number from a string

```
const allMatches = parseInt(soloStats[0]) + parseInt(duoStats[0]) + 
parseInt(squadStats[0])
```

Comment: You should however try to store them as integers or numbers if possible. Since these are scores for score keeping, I presume that they are integers or numbers to begin with but you somehow turned them into strings when you push them into arrays amirite?